# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list Ошибка на питоне

Tags: python, строки, vkontakte-api, type-error

Это мой первый пост на stack **overflow**

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 57, in <module>
    Дача - 3(40000$)"""), "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Вот код:

```
import vk_api
import random
import time
import datetime
import sqlite3
# token
token = "92c9c824e08f89deed7bc3e35429fe1d9e946b02838ee2764bc3a67864468439b9d1b19a88c8d26329a9d"


vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

vk._auth_token()


# conf
global db
global sql
db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
sql = db.cursor()

sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name TEXT,
    user_id TEXT,
    cash BIGINT,
    power BIGINT
)""")

db.commit()


while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
            id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
            body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
            if body.lower() == "начать" or body.lower() == "помощь":
                sql.execute(f'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = "{id}"')
                if sql.fetchone() is None:
                    user_info = vk.method("users.get", {"user_id": id, "fields": "first_name"})
                    user_name = user_info[0]["first_name"]

                    sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (user_name, id, 0, 1))
                    db.commit()
                else:
                    sql.execute(f'SELECT name FROM users WHERE user_id = "{id}"')
                    result = sql.fetchall()
                    print(result)
                    user_name = result
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": user_name + str(""", мои команды:
                Профиль
                Казино [сумма]
                Кубик [грань]
                Недвижимость [id]:
                Дом - 1(100000$)
                Машина - 2(50000$)
                Дача - 3(40000$)"""), "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif body.lower() == "Профиль":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Скоро!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})

    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Вы в 50 строке (там где `vk.method(...)`) хотите конкатенировать строки или списки?

Comment: Если все остальные посты будут такими же, то пусть лучше этот окажется и последним.

Comment: Вставьте блок кода, в котором произошла ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Вполне разумно, ошибка в строке

```
vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": user_name + str(""", мои команды:
            Профиль
            Казино [сумма]
            Кубик [грань]
            Недвижимость [id]:
            Дом - 1(100000$)
            Машина - 2(50000$)
            Дача - 3(40000$)"""), "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
```

`user_name` имеет тип `list` и вы пытаетесь его сконкатенировать со строкой, собственно ошибка вам об этом и говорит `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`, можете попробовать написать `"message": ' '.join(user_name) + ...` вместо `"message": user_name + ...`

Вкратце по коду, напишу про то, что бросилось в глаза:

1. Зачем писать так

```py
result = sql.fetchall()
print(result)
user_name = result
```

лучше было сразу написать так:

```py
    user_name = sql.fetchall()
    print(user_name)
```

На будущее лучше сразу приучивать логгировать промежуточные результаты

2. Зачем вы используете тройные двойные ковычки, для определения строки? Достаточно использовать одни двойные или одинарные. Тройные двойные ковычки обычно используются для описания функций и методов классов. Если вы хотите использовать ковычки внутри ковычек, то их можно просто экранировать: если поставить \ перед кавычкой (одинарной или двойной), это скажет интерпретатору о том, что кавычку нужно рассматривать не как начало или конец строки, а как часть строки.
3. У вас в Traceback написано, что ошибка в 57 строке, лучше было выложить сразу только 57 строку или лучше команду vk.method(...), потому что из всего этого полотна кода сложно сразу понять где ошибка(мне для этого пришлось переносить код в свой редактор и искать 57 строку)
4. Не стоит публично выкладывать ваш токен)

Ну и небольшие комментарии вцелом по посту. Всегда рад видеть новых людей на stackoverflow. Вы пишете пост в надежде найти помощь от комьюнити, что подразумевает то, что кто-то перейдет к вам в пост прочитает его, попробует его запустить и оставить комментарий, что потребует потратить свое свободное время, а учитывая, что время профессионалов стоит дорого(тут я не говорю про себя), нужно стараться как можно меньше его отнимать. Не совсем правильно писать Вот ошибка, вот код, дальше сами разбирайтесь, это ведь вам нужно решение;)